# MVC Model Binding EF 6 Missing Parent Reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have an object with a collection. I am passing the model to the view and upon post the collection is there, however the reference (containing object Id) is not there and the navigation property is null.

**Models**

```
  public class Order
    {
         public int OrderId { get; set;}
         public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set;}
    }

public class OrderItem 
{
     public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
     public int OrderId { get; set; }
     public int SomeOtherValue { get; set; } 
}
```

**View:**

```
@model Order
<h2>Edit Form</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OrderId)

       //Some other form fields for the order...

         @for (int i = 0; i < Model.OrderItems.Count; i++)
         {
             @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.OrderItems[i].SomeOtherValue)
         }
         <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

When I submit the form, the model gets bound correctly and the while debugging I can see the child OrderItems populated with updated information. However, the OrderId on each OrderItem is set to 0.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(Order myOrder)
        {
             myOrder.OrderItems.Count(); // These are populated and the edited values are there. 

             myOrder.OrderItem[0].Order; // this is null (all order items)
             myOrder.OrderItem[0].OrderId; // this is set to 0 (all order items) 

            //...more stuff and return view. 
        }
```

What is the best way to get around this problem? Is there some way to ensure that each OrderItem has a reference to the order when posting the form? I'm hoping I can avoid having to manually account for association in the controller when trying to save the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add hidden inputs for those fields. Check the code bolow:

..

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.OrderItems.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.OrderItems[i].OrderId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.OrderItems[i].Order)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.OrderItems[i].SomeOtherValue)
}
```

..

Comment: Haha...jeez...so simple. Thank you!